# IP Based Testing in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, grid, webdriver

Is it possible to run Automation Test cases using different IP's ? E.g I wanted to Trigger automation testing from Asia, US and Germany using 1 machine from Asia.

How do I achieve this requirement. suggestions are very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a selenium Grid setup where the nodes are running on VMs or docker containers and are using a vpn.

The response times and latency would definitely be a factor to consider though. 
I would instead try to fake the result by having a flag in the software under test that imitates what should happen in each country.